# TinyMCE: promlem with editing text within complex template HTML

Tags: tinymce

I'm using template plugin for inserting html snippets. For example:

```
<a class="button" href="#"><span class="button-inner"><span class="button-label">Button Text</span></span></a>
```

Everything goes fine until editor tries to change button's text and exit its html to add some more text after. The caret doesn't leave the A tag and stops within spans or before closing A tag. So in the end we get something like this:

```
...Button Text</span> some more </span> text here </a>
```

It breaks the layout completely.

Is there a way to mark the link as single solid block or spans as non-enterable with some attributes to prevent inserting text within unexpected places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `contenteditable="false"` attribute to make a portion of your HTML non-editable.  Here is an example:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Zxgaab

I changed your link HTML to this:

```
<a contenteditable="false" class="button" href="#">
  <span class="button-inner">
    <span class="button-label">
      Button Text
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

It will act like a single character in the editor...